# Laravel Request facade isn't detecting multiple submit buttons

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have two submit buttons within a form, and I need to detect which one is used to trigger a certain action. Unfortunately, my check isn't detecting which submit button was clicked:

**Form:**

```
<button type="submit" name="complete">
     <span class="btn-label">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
     </span> Submit Audit
</button>

<button type="submit" name="pending">
    <span class="btn-label">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
    </span> Save Audit
</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function updateAudit(Request $request, $id)
{
    ....

    if ($request->has('complete')) {
        $auditCompleteCheck->completed = 1;
        $auditCompleteCheck->save();
    }

}
```

If I output `$request`, I can see the `complete` submit button as: `"complete" => ""`, and similarly with pending: `"pending" => ""`.

But, if I `dd($request->has('complete'));`, it **always** returns false, even though I can see it in the request bag.

Why isn't the `->has` check working?

Many thanks.

Comment: The [`has()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L88) method will always return false for keys with empty input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the same value for the attribute `name` for both `button` elements and a different value for the attribute `value`.

HTML part:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_audit" value="complete">
     <span class="btn-label">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
     </span> Submit Audit
</button>

<button type="submit" name="submit_audit" value="pending">
    <span class="btn-label">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
    </span> Save Audit
</button>
```

Now in your controller, you can do the following:

```
if ($request->submit_audit === 'complete') {
    // Do something
}

if ($request->submit_audit === 'pending') {
    // Do something else
}
```